# Laravel custom auth filter

Tags: php, laravel-4, before-filter

I've added the standard auth filter to several routes using Route::Intended('/') in the controller (assuming login is successful).

filters.php:

```
Route::filter('auth', function(){
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('internal/login');
});
```

Controller:

```
if (Auth::attempt($data, false))
{
    return Redirect::intended('/');
}
```

How do I go about creating a custom auth filter that checks for a specific permission (isAdmin in this case)?

I've made the auth.admin filter the same as the standard auth filter to redirect to the login page, but do I need a second Login method on my controller or is there a way to tell which filter (if any) invoked the controller method?

```
if (Auth::attempt($data, false))
{
    if (RouteHasAdminFilter())
    {
        if (!Auth::User()->Admin)
            return Redirect::intended('/');
        else
            return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [@diegofelix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21602373/662581) for putting me on the right track.

I've managed to write a filter that:

- Prompts the user for their credentials
- Redirects to the homepage for non-admin users
- Allows an Admin user to go to the original URL

```
Route::filter('admin', function()  
{

    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('internal/login');

    if (Auth::check())
    {
        if (!Auth::User()->Admin)
            return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    else
        return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

This filter requires no changes to the Login method on my controller, which still uses Redirect::intended('/').
The key to this is *NOT* to redirect for Admin users, simply letting the code "fall through" to the original page, only non-admin users are redirected.
I'm also still using the standard "auth" filter to pages that require non-admin authentication.

My routes use either:

```
'before' => 'auth'
'before' => 'admin'
```

If I remove the first line of my admin filter (which I copied from the standard auth filter), I could get the same effect by using both filters together like so:

```
'before' => 'auth|admin'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect the user to a different if he is admin, you can do the check in the same Controller method.

```
if (Auth::attempt($data)
{
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        // admin
    else
        // not admin
}
else
    // login failed
```

In this case the isAdmin() is a method in the User Eloquent that checks if the user is admin.

If you want to do this check in other pages, you can create a filter that check if the user is admin like so:

```
Route::filter('admin', function(){

    if ( ! Auth::user()->isAdmin())
    {
        return Redirect::to('/')
         ->withError('No Admin, sorry.');
    }

});
```

Comment: I only want to direct if the user's an Admin and specific route(s) are being accessed (such as /admin). Could I set up an after filter to do the additional check and do a second re-direct?