# Controlling Access to Routes Laravel and Sentry

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am wondering how I can restrict access to certain routes in the `routes.php` file when using `Sentry`. Currently I have the following routes set up

```
Route::model('book', 'Book');
Route::get('/books', 'BookController@index');
Route::get('book/create', 'BookController@create');
Route::get('book/edit/{book}', 'BookController@edit');
Route::get('book/delete/{book}', 'BookController@delete');
Route::get('book/view/{book}', 'BookController@view');
Route::post('book/create', 'BookController@handleCreate');
Route::post('book/edit', 'BookController@handleEdit');
Route::post('book/delete', 'BookController@handleDelete');
```

I have 2 `groups`

1. Admin
2. User

I would only like the `Admin` to be able to access these routes. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598991/laravel-custom-auth-filter

Answer (score 0):

Taken from
http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/sentry-route-filters
and modified for your propose.  Hope this helps.  I implemented something similar to this recently.

Youll need to replace the routes in the failure redirects to your own though.

```
<?php 
/**
* Sentry filter
*
* Checks if the user is logged in
*/
Route::filter('Sentry', function()
{
    if ( ! Sentry::check()) {
        return Redirect::route('cms.login');
 }
});

/**
* hasAcces filter (permissions)
*
* Check if the user has permission (group/user)
*/
Route::filter('hasAccess', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    try
    {
        $user = Sentry::getUser();

        if( ! $user->hasAccess($value))
        {
            return Redirect::route('cms.login')->withErrors(array(Lang::get('user.noaccess')));
        }
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::route('cms.login')->withErrors(array(Lang::get('user.notfound')));
    }

});

/**
* InGroup filter
*
* Check if the user belongs to a group
*/
Route::filter('inGroup', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    try
    {
        $user = Sentry::getUser();

        $group = Sentry::findGroupByName($value);

        if( ! $user->inGroup($group))
        {
            return Redirect::route('cms.login')->withErrors(array(Lang::get('user.noaccess')));
        }
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::route('cms.login')->withErrors(array(Lang::get('user.notfound')));
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupNotFoundException $e)
    {
        return Redirect::route('cms.login')->withErrors(array(Lang::get('group.notfound')));
    }
});


//Example use

Route::group(array('before' => 'Sentry|inGroup:Admin'), function()
{
    Route::model('book', 'Book');
    Route::get('/books', 'BookController@index');
    Route::get('book/create', 'BookController@create');
    Route::get('book/edit/{book}', 'BookController@edit');
    Route::get('book/delete/{book}', 'BookController@delete');
    Route::get('book/view/{book}', 'BookController@view');
    Route::post('book/create', 'BookController@handleCreate');
    Route::post('book/edit', 'BookController@handleEdit');
    Route::post('book/delete', 'BookController@handleDelete');
});
```

Comment: is there maybe a way to implement a multiple filter that will return the route in case that at least one filter is true? For example like this: Route::get('users', array('as' => 'getUsers', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getIndex', 'before' => 'inGroup:Administrator|hasAccess:users.index')); or do i need also for the admin group define all these permissions which are also in other groups? Now I have only 1 for admin group which is global so admin can access to everything and specific for other groups